# Java - как сделать при нажатии на кнопку что бы что то происходило

Tags: java

Так как я только начал знакомиться с Java, толком ничего не знаю.
Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать графическое приложение в WindowBuilder.
Всё хорошо, но одного не могу понять.
Допустим я нажал на кнопку, мне нужно что бы что то происходило. В моём случае вылезло диалоговое окно.
Кто знает как это осуществить?
Вот код (только кнопка на которую нужно сделать действие):

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Info");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(274, 13, 61, 23);
    frmCookieClientLauncherlogin.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    if(btnNewButton.//и тут что то надо вписать.//) {

    }
```

Буду рад всем ответам.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JButtonaddActionListenerActionListeneract.htm

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо <3

Answer (score 1):

У каждого компонента есть метод `addKeyListener()`, которые отвечает за обработку нажатия клавиш на клавиатур.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Test button");
ActionListener actionListener = new TestActionListener();
button.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

создаем экземпляр нашего слушателя `TestActionListener`, а затем добавляем его в качестве слушателя к кнопке с помощью вызова `addActionListener()` и передаем ему экземпляр обработчика.